# Is it possible to click the back button in the browser using Playwright?

Tags: javascript, typescript, playwright

In a browser there's often arrow buttons that go forward and backward in history:

[image]

Can these buttons be clicked on via playwright?

There's no elements for them so I was wondering if this is possible...

```js
await navigationObject(page).backButton.click();
```

Answer (score 15):

### For nodejs

```
await page.goBack()
```

Or

```
await page.goForward()
```

### For python

```
await page.go_back()
```

Or

```
await page.go_forward()
```

You can find more info here: https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-page#page-go-back

Comment: I also use the same approach with success

Comment: For C# - await Page.GoBackAsync();

Answer (score 0):

Try the History API:

```
window.history.back()
```

and

```
window.history.forward()
```

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API